# alphanumeric username in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am making a textfield in which the user will enter only alphanumeric password.i want to validate it through javascript but it is not validating.

```
<script>
function valid()
{

var flag;
var alphaExp=/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
if(!(myform.uname.value.match(alphaExp)))
{
 alert("Username must contain Alphabet and Number Both");
 myform.user.focus();
 return false;
}

}

</script>
```

here myform is the name of form and uname is the name of textfield

can anyone tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: What? I don't understand why people limit what characters people can put in their password. **Who cares?** It doesn't concern you, the webmaster, whatsoever. You should be focusing on making sure it's a *good* password instead.

Comment: @Marc B it doesnt show me the alert message If I only enter the number or alphabet

Comment: @animuson to make a good password you It must have character + numbers + special characters

Comment: @Sharpzain120: `only alphanumeric password` means only letters and numbers... Also, in order to force a number *and* letter, you'll need two separate checks. Your check is only making sure there is at least 1 letter *or* number.

Comment: @animuson: probably because they're not doing proper DB sanitization and anyone who's using a `'` in their pw must be up to no good.

Comment: @animuson: I think *only alphanumeric password* means *only passwords consisting of both letters and numbers* here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to make the use letters **and** numebrs in their password.

`var alphaExp=/([a-z].*[0-9])|([0-9].*[a-z])/i;`

should work for that.

Comment: @Sharpzain120 It makes the regex case-insensitive, so `/[a-z]/i` is equivalent to `/[A-Za-z]/`.

Comment: It will know. I fixed it. My answer had a typo. Also, I simplified it a little. I'm still not perfectly sure if you want to allow non-alphanumeric characters (like `#`, for example). The above **will** allow them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
function valid()
{

var flag;
var alphaExp=/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
if ( !alphaExp.test(myform.uname.value) )
{
 alert("Username must contain Alphabet and Number Both");
 myform.user.focus();
 return false;
}

}

</script>
```